# error: not an enclosing class i can't fix it

Tags: android-studio

How to fix this?

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(ViewStudentActivity.this, ViewStudentByBranchYear.class);
            intent.putExtra("year", year);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please include the full error message

Comment: ViewStudentByBranchYear is an activity or it is a java file